# Interpreting Results of Classification Tree

Tags: r, rpart

This isn't much of a coding oriented question as it is asking what rpart does during plotting and how to interpret the results. Usually classification trees are straightforward to read, but this one threw me off.

[image]

As you can see Demo_Generation=bdf and bcdf are a bit confusing to read. What are they? And what is cdfi in Demo_MaritalStatus. The values for these respectively are:

**Demo_Generation**

- Gen X
- Millenial
- The Silent Generation
- The Greatest Generation
- Baby Boomers
- Gen Z

**Demo_Fico**
 - Poor

- Fair
- Good
- Very Good
- Exceptional

**Demo_MaritalStatus**

- Domestic Partner
- Married
- Single
- Separated
- Unmarried

Comment: rpart tree plots are always difficult to read. I recommend you to have a look at the `visTree` function from `visNetwork` package. More info: http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/tree.html

Comment: how did I get downvoted for providing basically all of the information I could give + program related issue :/ doesn't make sense to me sometimes.

Comment: @jlesuffleur visTree is perfect. Thank you so much.